# RelativeLayout design issue: ScrollView between a RelativeLayout and a Button

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

The layout of my activity must be as follows:

- screen is divided into 3 sections (3 "rows")
- first section consists of an image to the left, and two TextViews next to it.
- second section is a large text, put into a ScrollView so it can be scrolled.
- third section is just a button, and this button must be at the bottom of the screen always.

So, both the 1st and 3rd sections must be fixed, only the 2nd section can be scrolled.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1">      

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text " />

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/relativeLayout2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is pretty obvious here:

[image]

The text in the middle section can be scrolled alright, but the problem is the fact that the ScrollView doesn't "end" when the button "begins" in the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text BIG BIG text " />
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/relativeLayout2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works, thanks very much! Will accept when I'm allowed (3 mins) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add that you can solve this using a RelativeLayout as the outermost layout (instead of LinearLayout as in Luksprogs example). Lets say you have two views: viewAbove and viewBelow, and you want to fill the space between the two views with another view. Add this to the latter view:

```
android:layout_below="@id/viewAbove"
android:layout_above="@id/viewBelow"
```